# Incorrect aggregation when using sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I use this query to get search hits and the count of hits across multiple indices:

```
/index1,index2/_search
{
  "query":{
    "query_string":{
      "query":"*"
    }
  },
  "aggs":{
    "group_by_index":{
      "terms":{
        "field":"_index",
        "min_doc_count":0
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter":{
    "terms":{
      "_index":"index1"
    }
  },
  "sort":{
    "my_field":"asc"
  }
}
```

The problem is if I sort on a field (my_field) that only exist in `index1`, the aggregation will only give me the hits count of `index1`, and not `index2`.

I thought the aggregation would work regardless of what sorting I have specified?

Using Elasticsearch 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using [unmapped_type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-request-sort.html#_ignoring_unmapped_fields)